# How to fetch First open and close status in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sample data like this :

```
   ID Val   Name        Dt                 Status
    1, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 02:18:00', 'open'
    2, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 04:04:00', 'open'
    3, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 04:10:00', 'close'
    4, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 05:50:00', 'open'
    5, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 05:56:00', 'close'
    6, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 07:36:00', 'open'
    7, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 07:40:00', 'open'
    8, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 07:42:00', 'close'
```

How can i get the output like this  :

```
   ID Val   Name        Dt                 Status
        1, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 02:18:00', 'open'
        3, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 04:10:00', 'close'
        4, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 05:50:00', 'open'
        5, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 05:56:00', 'close'
        6, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 07:36:00', 'open'
        8, 145, 'Test', '2020-01-28 07:42:00', 'close'
```

I have tried using Row_number but unable to fetch proper result set .

```
Select * from  (
select *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY vehicle_id,status )R from test_sam  )T
Where T.R= 1 ORDER BY id
```

Can anyone suggest how to proceed .

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: @P.Salmon OP tries to use `ROW_NUMBER()` - so he has 8+ version.

Comment: @akina what op says is 'unable to fetch proper result set .' - It may well be that is on 8+ - on the other hand..

Comment: @P.Salmon I perceive *unable to fetch **proper** result set* like "query executes without error, but gives wrong output".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to select all records for which `status` is not the same as in previous record (if exists - the most ancient seems to be returned unconditionally).

```
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT *, 
       COALESCE(LAG(Status) OVER (ORDER BY dt), 'unknown') prev_status
FROM test_sam
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE Status != prev_status
ORDER BY dt;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ade7e16c2cbab2ba0120e5036a8463d)

Answer (score 2):

**MYSQL 5**

MySQL does not guarantee the order but in this case the table looks like a log that inserts the data in order. So you can use:

```
SET @previous_value = '';

SELECT *,
       IF(@previous_value = status, 0 , 1) AS RowNumber,
       @previous_value := status
FROM Table1
HAVING RowNumber > 0
ORDER BY id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cfrhWey8oVKGK83XELJCsb/20)

I save in `previous_value` the value of `status` that is in the row above.
Before it changes I check if it is equal to current row.
Finally with `HAVING()` I exclude double values, i.e. those with 0

---

**MYSQL 8**

I recommend using Akina's solution. It works the same way as mine but it doesn't use variables that are deprecated in MySQL 8

Comment: . . This is a bad use of variables.   You are depending on the order of evaluation of the expressions in the `select`, but MySQL explicitly does not guarantee that ordering.  In addition, variables are deprecated in MySQL 8+.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Mysql does not guarantee the order but in this case the table looks like a log that inserts the data in order.
I didn't know the variables in Mysql 8+ were deprecated, do you have a manual where it explains it?

Comment: For the rest I agree with you, if Mohan111 uses mysql 8 Akira's solution is the best :D

Comment: . . "Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL." . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html.

Comment: thank you so much for teaching me something I didn't know. I have changed my answer

Comment: . . There is much that I have learned in essentially the same way.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution would work.

```
SELECT *  from test OP
where dt =  
  (SELECT min(dt) dt from test 
  where status = 'open' and val = OP.val)
  UNION ALL
SELECT *  from test OP
where dt =  
  (SELECT min(dt) dt from test 
  where status = 'close' and val = OP.val)
```

kindly refer [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/408521/9/0)