# How to transpose rows to columns based on time intervals in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sample data like this :

```
            ID Val   Name        Dt                 Status
            1, 145, 'Test1', '2020-01-28 02:18:00', 'open'
            2, 145, 'Test2', '2020-01-28 04:10:00', 'open'
            3, 145, 'Test3', '2020-01-28 05:50:00', 'open'
            4, 145, 'Test3', '2020-01-28 05:56:00', 'close'
            5, 145, 'Test4', '2020-01-28 07:36:00', 'open'
            6, 145, 'Test4', '2020-01-28 07:42:00', 'open'
            7, 145, 'Test4', '2020-01-28 07:44:00', 'open'
            8, 145, 'Test4', '2020-01-28 07:47:00', 'close'
```

How can i get the output like this :

```
        ID Val   Name        o_Dt                 o_gate      c_Dt             c_gate
        1, 145, 'Test1', '2020-01-28 02:18:00', 'open'        NULL               NULL
        2, 145, 'Test2', '2020-01-28 04:10:00', 'open'        NULL               NULL
        3, 145, 'Test3', '2020-01-28 05:50:00', 'open'  '2020-01-28 05:56:00', 'close'
        4, 145, 'Test4', '2020-01-28 07:36:00', 'open'  '2020-01-28 07:47:00', 'close'
```

I Have tried with different scenarios but not moving forward 
Using

`COALESCE(LAG(Status) OVER (ORDER BY dt)`

```
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY vehicle_id,status )
```

Not getting exact result . Can anyone suggest on this  .

Previously I have asked question for same data set but now requirement got changed .

Link : 
[How to fetch First open and close status in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334591/how-to-fetch-first-open-and-close-status-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment106728903_60334591)

Comment: . . The logic for `close_date` doesn't make sense to me.  There is only one row with `'close'` on it in the original data, but somehow you turn this into two close dates.

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff I have modified the Input data .Please have a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by val, name order by date) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'open' and
      (prev_status is null or prev_status <> 'open');
```

This can return more than one result for a test, if the status can "return" to `'open'`.  You can use `row_number()` if you don't want this behavior:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by val, name, status order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'open' and seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

(for adjusted data)

You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select val, name,
       min(case when status = 'open' then status end) as o_gate,
       min(case when status = 'open' then dt end) as o_dt,
       max(case when status = 'close' then status end) as c_gate,
       max(case when status = 'close' then dt end) as c_dt,
from t
group by val, name;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e8e28d1e8ff519554ac98ba5e1beb18) is a db<>fiddle

If you want to reconstruct the `id`, you can use an expression like:

```
row_number() over (order by min(dt)) as id
```

Comment: but this one will not give open date and close date @Gordon Linoff

Comment: I have tried conditional aggregation but it is not working when I add other columns in the select statement.

Comment: @mohan111 . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a NEW question.

Comment: with the same columns it self it is not giving exact result it is grouping on name  @gordon It is not giving exact result

Comment: @mohan111 . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  This returns *exactly* the results you specified.  Your question has been answered. If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: ok @gordon It is working accordingly But my data i have provided it is not that perfect

Comment: @mohan111 . . . It is only possible to answer the question you have asked.  This answers that question.

Comment: sure @gordon .I will do